# SVG@Chrome: No animation in clipPath

Tags: html, css, svg, animated, svg-animate

I found another problem with SVG, this time in Chrome.

I tried to prepare a preloader with CSS animation and ClipPath.

It works excellent in Safari, a little worse in Firefox (transform-origin problem :) ) but in Chrome 47 is total failure. It doesn't even display animated element.

I thought Chrome is unsurpassed with SVG implementation. But now I totally fool and hope someone else will help to find the way ;).

I put this example on Codepen:
http://tinyurl.com/jsdfjpu

Thank you in advance for any light in tunnel of my ignorance ;).

Comment: I'm on Chrome _Version 47.0.2526.111 m_ and your Codepen seems to be working fine for me. Maybe it's supposed to look/behave different than it is, but I have no reference for the objective.

Comment: @hungerstar, Can you see the graphic inside the rotating circle? There shoud be animated vector shape "360°"

Comment: Looks like a repaint bug. In the inspector, if you toggle any css property on any of the SVG nodes really fast, you can see the animation is being calculated properly... bummer. Cool design though!

Comment: @swider, thanks for analysis.. you're right... I also checked it. Chrome is trying to draw it without success. It can be seen while you resize window with opened inspector  - could be problem with rendering animation inside ClipPath.